# Change dimensions of shape by pixels in Photoshop CS6

Tags: shapes, pixel, dimensions

I have created a rectangle with Photoshop CS6.

Now I want to alter its width and height by pixels, is that possible?

I know I can create the rectangle by clicking and choosing its width and height, but how to change it later?

On the Info panel I can see the dimensions in pixels but I cannot change them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy one.

Enter `Free Transform` mode (Edit > Free Transform or <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and, at the top of your window, you will see these boxes:

[image: percent]

Where you see "100%" in the width and height, simply enter the pixel value that you wish it to be:

[image: pixels]

Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> until your changes are applied.

Comment: They really should have made that more obvious